# Make polygon with 4000 points editable in google map v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been using polygons in google map v3 and I am able to create and edit polygons.

Recently I had to create a polygon with approximately 4000 points. There is no issue in plotting this polygon on the map when the editable property is kept false.

However as soon as I set the "editable" property to true or use the setEditable function as shown below the script becomes unresponsive.

```
polygon.setEditable(true);
```

The script hangs completely in Mozilla Firefox. Chrome does a slight better job but there too the map becomes laggy and slow.

This issue is present only when I edit a polygon with a high number of points. Smaller polygons are editable without any problems.

Is there a way to ensure that the polygon can be made editable without the browser hanging? If making the entire polygon editable is not possible can some portion of the polygon be made editable? I have tried searching for a solution but haven't been able to find anything yet. Any help / suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the issue solved???

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you ran out of memory because of too much points. I would suggest you to create your big polygon with small polygons, that way you will be able to edit it without the browser hanging

Comment: I do not have control over the number of points as users create the polygon. Also creating smaller polygons won't work because I need it to be a single polygon as I run as point in polygon algorithm on it. As I have mentioned plotting it with the editable option to false works perfectly. It is only when the editable property is true that the issue occurs. I need a solution for that.

Comment: As @Sasa suggests, you can divide your big polygon into smaller ones, then apply your point in polygon algorithm on Union(polygonA, polygonB,...) etc. However, this is a little bit more complex ; but the only other way seems to restrict the users create a polygon with so much points.